# TCP flow extraction

Tags: tcp

I need to extract TCP Flows with their content from dump file and then save their flow into other file each flow separately

Answer (score 7):

You definitely want to use [Bro](http://bro-ids.org), more specifically, its contents.bro policy. For example, given a trace that contains HTTP requests, running the following ...

```
bro -r http.trace -f 'tcp and port 80' contents
```

... produces files

```
contents.[senderIP].[senderPort]-[destIP].[destPort]
contents.[destIP].[destPort]-[senderIP].[senderPort]
```

for each connection, each containing the unidirectional content of the flow.

The flow reassembly is highly robust, the process scales to very large files, and everything is customizable to your needs.

Comment: This somehow doesn't work. I cannot find `contents.bro` anywhere.

Comment: In recent Bro releases, look for scripts/base/protocols/conn/contents.bro.

Answer (score 6):

If you're only doing a few, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can do this.

Steps:

1. Open up the capture in Wireshark.
2. Click on a packet from the TCP connection you're interested in
3. Analyze -> Follow TCP Stream
4. Click 'Raw'
5. Select (from the popup menu) one of 'Entire Conversation' or one of the two directions.
6. Click 'Save As'

Alternate steps, for HTTP only:

1. Open up the capture
2. Select File -> Export -> Objects -> HTTP
3. A dialog will open showing all the HTTP objects in the capture. You can save some or all of them.

This is with Wireshark 1.2.1 on Linux/GTK. The 'follow TCP stream' option has been moved around between versions, so it may be somewhere else if you have an older version. But its always been called *Follow TCP Stream* so you should be able to find it.

Quick searching also reveals several other options if Wireshark doesn't work for you: ngrep, tcpick, chaosreader, and tcpflow.

Answer (score 4):

```
tcpflow -r my_dump_file.pcap -o output_dir/
```

It will extract each tcp flow, separately, into a file under output_dir. Each flow in its own file.

Here's the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/tcpflow.1.html) with more options

Comment: You need to add `-a` to unzip gzipped data

Answer (score 1):

[Wire shark](http://www.wireshark.org/) maybe? It can be used to filter sessions and I think you can then save them seperatly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at [NetFlow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflow) and related tools.